# How to style the iOS6 file input control?

Tags: html, css, ios, ios6

I am glad the file input control for files has finally arrived to the iPhone with iOS 6.

However, the display looks kind of odd. Does anyone know ways to style the control?

Comment: You know file-inputs areall VERY browser-specific, and styling likely is also? Perhaps you'll end up with a kind of CSS-hack with laying out another element on top of it.

Comment: Update: before there will be a way to downscale an image before submitting it in a form field, this "new" feature in iOS 6 is useless. It takes way to long on a mobile network to upload pics with 2 MB and more. We have opted to program an iOS app instead to wrap our website and catch the file input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the OK solution for iOS:

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input accept="image/jpeg" name="pic" id="pic" type="file">
  <a onmousedown="myClick();">
  Choose a new picture
  </a>
  <br> 
  <input value="put up the picture" type="submit"> 
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#pic {
  display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function myClick() {
  document.getElementById('pic').click();
}
```

Or on CSSdeck:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/kmyjvuwb

This works fine in current Firefox and Chrome, too, but alas, not in IE (the file is not uploaded!)...

Answer (score 8):

Simple, you can hide the element and you can fire their click event.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="uploader" />
<u>Choose file</u>
```

CSS:

```
input.uploader {
    visibility:hidden;
    height: 0;
}
u { 
    display: block; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 15px; 
    text-align: center; 
    background: #ddd; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
}
```

JS (with JQuery):

```
$('u').click(function(){
    $('input[name=photo]').trigger('click');
});
```

Sample: http://uploader.gokercebeci.com/

Comment: Do you know if this is possible without relying on a native click? I can get this working, but when I try to fire the click from the console in a WebView it doesn't work.

Comment: I do not have a mac or an IOS development platform, also I can not try it on WebView. It's working on Safari on my 3GS IOS6 though.

But if you use a fast click javascript, it can disable fire events. I've experienced the problem with https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick and my solution was adding a CSS class "needsclick" in the element.

Comment: Goker: the "Sample" page requires authentification, and I cannot get your code to work: http://cssdeck.com/labs/rqpvvgeg or http://jsfiddle.net/qFeCA/.

Comment: @goker.cebeci Adding "needsclick" as a class on the target element works great. Thank you!